# How to move tree leaf nodes horizontally after automatic positioning?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikz-trees, tikz-qtree, forest

I'd like to draw trees like the following:

[desired tree display http://quicklatex.com/cache3/ql_c0f6b5397c19caf09ce70d6e47841eb7_l3.png](http://quicklatex.com/cache3/ql_c0f6b5397c19caf09ce70d6e47841eb7_l3.png)

That is, I have edges which are crossing. The tree should be drawn like a regular tree (without crossings) except at the last level where the leaves can be in any horizontal order. The number of nodes etc. is arbitrary, the image is just an example.

The only thing I know about the tree is (a) its structure, that is, nodes and their children, and (b) an ordering number (=x position) for each leaf which determines where the leaves should be displayed horizontally to form the crossings. In the example above, I would know `a1` is at position 0, `b1` at 1, `a2` at 2, and `b2` at 3. I can use these numbers when I draw a specific leaf.

The code must represent the structure of the tree, like that:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{frontier/.style={distance from root=70pt}}
  \Tree [.Z [.\node{A};
                \node{a1};
                \node{a2}; ]
              [.\node{B};
                \node{b1};
                \node{b2}; ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[non-crossing tree display http://quicklatex.com/cache3/ql_4217cf1d35018cf2016b55ac580d6085_l3.png](http://quicklatex.com/cache3/ql_4217cf1d35018cf2016b55ac580d6085_l3.png)

Ideally, now I'd like to reorder the leaves based on their ordering numbers that I know:

```
  \Tree [.Z [.\node{A};
                \node at (0,0) {a1};
                \node at (2,0) {a2}; ]
              [.\node{B};
                \node at (1,0) {b1};
                \node at (3,0) {b2}; ] ]
```

The problem is that this becomes:

[wrong tree http://quicklatex.com/cache3/ql_8b543330e2e251476b91100f13dcca4a_l3.png](http://quicklatex.com/cache3/ql_8b543330e2e251476b91100f13dcca4a_l3.png)

Question: How can the repositioning of the leaves be achieved without loosing the automatic tree layout functionality of `tikz-qtree`?

Some background: These are derivation trees generated recursively by so-called multiple context-free grammars which can model languages like a^i b^j a^i b^j. I appended numbers to the terminals to make it more explicit where they end up when reordered.

Comment: What should it look like? If the nodes are automatically laid out, you get the first result. If you specify them, they go where you say. I don't understand how they can be both repositioned and automatically laid out.

Comment: I only want to specify where the leaf nodes should be after positioning the tree like usual, you could think of it like a post-processing step where the leaf nodes are moved somewhere in the horizontal line where they are. Edit: The problem is that I don't want to use the standard tikz left-of etc. positioning as it will overlap in most cases.

Comment: See my edited answer for a way to automate the count of the total number of leaves. I can't guarantee this won't break but it works for your example, so it should at least give you some potentially useful ideas.

Comment: Just tested it for a bigger one, seems to work just fine! http://i.imgur.com/UUfWDAw.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

Note that I'm not at all sure I understand what you are trying to do.

In your comments on Gonzalo Medina's answer, you say you know that 'a' must end up in position 0 and 2, and 'b' in position 1 and 3, say. But it isn't clear how you expect this to be automated. (How can TeX tell the difference between 1 'a' and another? There is no input word 'abab' in your example code, so this information doesn't seem to be provided in any form.)

`forest` allows you to create 'dynamic' trees i.e. you can move stuff around at various stages. Here, I shift the nodes after the layout of the tree is computed but before it is drawn:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      where n children=0{
        s sep=1.5em,
        inner xsep=0pt
      }{},
    }
    [Z
      [A
        [a1
        ]
        [a2, before drawing tree={x+=1.5em}
        ]
      ]
      [B
        [b1, before drawing tree={x-=1.5em}
        ]
        [b2
        ]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: shifting nodes after layout is computed]

## EDIT

The OP edited the question to demonstrate a solution based on my answer above and discussion in comments. However, that solution required manually specifying the total number of leaf nodes. I *think* that the following should avoid this requirement. The idea is to increment a LaTeX counter for each leaf node and then use the final value of this counter to adjust the position of the node before the tree is drawn. A new style, `leaf position` is defined which takes one argument which should be the position of the node in the ordered sequence i.e. `leaf position=2` if the leaf should end up in the third (number 2) slot.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begingroup

\newcounter{leafnodes}
\setcounter{leafnodes}{0}
\forestset{
  leaf position/.style={
    before drawing tree={
      where n children=0{
        x/.pgfmath={(#1-(.5*\theleafnodes)+.5)*1.5em}
      }{},
    }
  },
}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    where n children=0{
      s sep=1.5em,
      inner xsep=0pt,
      delay={TeX={\stepcounter{leafnodes}}},
    }{},
  },
  [Z
    [A
      [a1, leaf position=0
      ]
      [a2, leaf position=2
      ]
    ]
    [B
      [b1, leaf position=1
      ]
      [b2, leaf position=3
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image: automate calculation of total number of leaf nodes]

## EDIT EDIT

In response to the discussion in comments, here's an example which puts all of the leaf nodes on the same level, using `tier=leaves`, and which sets the height of these nodes to a standard size so that the edges drawn from the parents do not terminate at different heights. I've also moved the leftmost node a bit left since it looked a bit odd with a larger tree. Obviously this could be adjusted further if desired.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begingroup

\newcounter{leafnodes}
\setcounter{leafnodes}{0}
\forestset{
  leaf position/.style={
    before drawing tree={
      where n children=0{
        x/.pgfmath={(#1-(.5*\theleafnodes))*1.5em}
      }{},
    }
  },
}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    where n children=0{
      s sep=1.5em,
      inner xsep=0pt,
      tier=leaves,
      text height=5pt,
      delay={TeX={\stepcounter{leafnodes}}},
    }{},
  },
  [Z
    [A
      [A
        [A
          [T, leaf position=6
          ]
          [y, leaf position=1
          ]
          [e, leaf position=0
          ]
        ]
        [a, leaf position=5
        ]
        [a, leaf position=4
        ]
      ]
      [a1, leaf position=8
      ]
      [a2, leaf position=2
      ]
    ]
    [B
      [b1, leaf position=7
      ]
      [b2, leaf position=3
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image: levelled leaves]

Comment: This is getting closer. Sorry for the confusion... to make it absolutely clear (I hope): forget about the double 'a's etc. What I know is: I know in which order each leaf node should be at the bottom, that is, a1 at position 0, b1 at 1, a2 at 2, and b2 at 3. I have these numbers and can use them in the code for the respective nodes, that is, in `[a2, before drawing tree={x+=1.5em}` I can use the number `2` somehow, which is more or less equivalent to an *absolute* position. Your solution is based on relative positions, and I don't know how to infer the relative ones from the absolute ones.

Comment: @neo Well, `xy` is the absolute coordinate system as opposed to `ls` which is relative to the tree. You could say e.g. `x=...` and then multiply the distance by the number i.e. it doesn't have to be `x+=` or `x-=`. It can just be `x=`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Well, you used `forest` first. But I already gave you (+1), so I can't reciprocate further ;). The dynamic tree stuff is weirdly cool. Have you heard anything further about testing the new beta?

Comment: @cfr I just tested your code but it shows differently then your image: http://oi62.tinypic.com/24fhhm9.jpg Did you forget anything?

Comment: @neo I just copied the code back from my answer above, compiled it and got the same result I posted earlier. You didn't by any chance omit the `delay` did you? I can reproduce the result you posted if I take that out.

Comment: @cfr Yes, the dynamic tree keys are powerful; I remember I used some of those features in an answer here some time ago. Regarding the beta-testing, no, I haven heard anything.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Can you reproduce the problem the OP reports with my code? I copied it back and recompiled, but my tree still looks like the one I posted in the 'Edit' section, and not like the one the OP seems to be getting.

Comment: @cfr No; I used the code just below "EDIT" and this is what I got: http://imgur.com/q2rp6AU (same result as in the image you posted). Perhaps neo's system is using outdated packages?

Comment: Yes, my `pgf` version was too old. I had 2.10, with 3.0.0 it works now. Maybe `forest` should throw an error in such a case, assuming it is some feature that `forest` uses which is buggy in pgf 2.10.

Comment: @cfr: Can you add `tier=word,` to the leaf style? Then it replicates the `frontier/.style={distance from root` part of my original code. Otherwise it looks really bad for bigger non-symmetric trees.

Comment: @neo Yes. That shouldn't be a problem. Did you get weird results when you added it? I would probably add it to the `where n children=0{...` part of the code within the tree.

Comment: @cfr: The `+0.5` you removed was there assuming the middle of the leaves is equal to the root and also equal to x=0, but yeah, this of course is only the case for more or less symmetrical trees.

Comment: @neo I just did it to even out the example. I figured you would adjust it as required anyway ;).

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to switch to the powerful [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package, this can be easily done:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
  parent anchor=south,
  child anchor=north,
  l sep=0.75cm
}
[Z,s sep=-40pt
  [A,calign=fixed edge angles,calign primary angle=-30,calign secondary angle=60
    [a1]
    [a2]
  ]
  [B,calign=fixed edge angles,calign primary angle=-60,calign secondary angle=30
    [b1]
    [b2]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, how would I calculate the angles (or use something else?) if I only have the x coordinates of the leaves?

Comment: @neo I am not sure I understand your question. Can you please give a real example of the situation mentioned?

Comment: Sure, let's say the leaves are "a", "a", "b", "b" in normal tree alignment. My input word was "abab", and I know which character belongs to which position in the input word. That is, "a"->0, "a"->2, "b"->1, "b"->3 when starting to count at zero. And this is the only information I got for aligning the leaf nodes. I want to align them like the input word.

Comment: I added an explanation in the question to make it more clear hopefully, sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Derived from cfr's original answer and comments:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begingroup

\def\f{1.5em} % scale
\def\n{4} % number of leaves

\def\xleaf#1{\f*(#1-\n/2+0.5)} % calculates x of a leaf
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    where n children=0{
      s sep=1.5em,
      inner xsep=0pt
    }{},
  }
  [Z
    [A
      [a1, before drawing tree={x=\xleaf{0}}
      ]
      [a2, before drawing tree={x=\xleaf{2}}
      ]
    ]
    [B
      [b1, before drawing tree={x=\xleaf{1}}
      ]
      [b2, before drawing tree={x=\xleaf{3}}
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

I guess this is as far as it gets. A shame that it needs the total number of leaves though but I guess it's too complicated to derive that automatically from the tree and then use it inside the `before drawing tree` expressions.

Note: cfr's updated answer can count leaves now!